# Не могу воспользоваться сторонней библиотекой в nestjs

Tags: npm, модули, library, nestjs

возникла проблема с использованием сторонней библиотеки.
Вот ссылка на библиотеку https://www.npmjs.com/package/cyrillic-to-translit-js
Если в кратце, то по идее она должна преобразовывать строку кириллицы в латиницу. Но когда пытаюсь сделать как написано в описании, т.е. создать

```
const a = new CyrillicToTranslit();
this.logger.warn(a.transform('Привет'));
```

NestJS выдает ошибку `TypeError: cyrillic_to_translit_js_1.default is not a constructor.`
Я только учусь и многого не знаю, поэтому скорее всего мой вопрос покажется вам довольно тупым, но если кто в курсе почему так, ответьте. Использую в сервисе, уже пробовал импортировать ее в модуль, но тогда выдает другую ошибку мол обнаружена круговая зависимость.

```
Error: A circular dependency has been detected. Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are decorated with "forwardRef()".
```

##### Просьба

Не рекомендуйте других пакетов, я знаю что они есть и работают как надо.
Например https://www.npmjs.com/package/transliteration

Если вам не сложно, ответьте на вопрос, в чем все-таки проблема, хочу понять как фиксят такое, чтобы в будущем столкнувшись с чем-то подобным знать как поступать, ведь другого пакета может и не быть.

Comment: У меня тоже тупой вопрос, а вы её импортировали import CyrillicToTranslit from 'cyrillic-to-translit-js';?

Comment: Да импортировал, как я уже говорил, другие библиотеки с задачей справляются, а с этой наблюдаю такую непонятную (лично мне) проблему.

Comment: Попробуйте вернуться к первой ошибке и `import cyrillicToTranslit from 'cyrillic-to-translit-js'`, либо `const cyrillicToTranslit = require('cyrillic-to-translit-js')` (не знаю, можно ли у вас так) и `cyrillicToTranslit().transform('Привет')`. У меня это работает с верисией 3.1.0

Comment: У вас это работает в сервисе NestJS или в обычном js файле вне какого-то фреймворка? в обычном и у меня все работает, и проблема как раз в том что не могу его заюзать в фреймворке и не понимаю почему.

Comment: У меня это в Express работает, про конкретно Nestjs, увы, ничего не могу сказать.